# Embeddings of number fields into $\mathbb{C}$ or $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}_l$

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, galois-representations

When studying arithmetic Galois representations for a number field $F$ one often fixes at the outset an embedding of its algebraic closure $\bar{F}$ into $\mathbb{C}$ or $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}_l$ and proceeds with the implicit assumption that choosing another embedding would not alter anything. It appears analogous to choosing a base point of a topological space for the ease of working with its fundamental group rather than fundamental groupoid.

It seems natural to ask:

(1) What is the structure of the set of embeddings of $\bar{F}$ into $\mathbb{C}$ (or $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}_l$)?

(2) Are there examples of significant proofs that have relied crucially on using more than one embedding, or of situations in which variations of objects with respect to embeddings arise?

EDIT: I have made a significant change above: from $F$ to $\bar{F}$. My apologies to the first three commenters, and many thanks as well. It's their comments which at first puzzled me and then made me realize where I had made the mistake.

Comment: (2) Dirichlet unit theorem

Comment: (1) It is a $\operatorname{Gal}(\bar{F}/F)$-set.

Comment: @Felipe Voloch, that's a nice example, although when I had thought of the question, I had in the back of my mind information derived from successive embeddings rather than simultaneous ones as in the unit theorem.

Comment: @S. Carnahan, thanks for pointing it out. I was secretly hoping the set of embeddings to turn out to be a top. space or site on which the Gal(\bar{F}/F)$ action can be analyzed. Other kinds of structures would be nice too, of course - compatible with the Galois action.

Comment: The set of embeddings of F into any other field is a *finite* set, so it's unlikely to have an interesting structure as a topological space, site, etc.

Comment: Because $F$ has no transcendental elements, this set is just a torsor for the group of field automorphisms of $\bar{F}$, i.e., $\operatorname{Gal}(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$.  I note that you don't have any conditions involving $F$ itself.  If you fix an embedding of $F$ into $\mathbb{C}$ or $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}_\ell$, and ask for the set of extensions to embeddings of $\bar{F}$, then the set is a torsor under $\operatorname{Gal}(\bar{F}/F)$.